# Error when deploying app on azure app service

Tags: python, azure, azure-web-app-service, requirements.txt

I get this error message when I deploy my app from github to the azure app service.

× python setup.py egg_info did not run successfully.
│ exit code: 1
╰─> [16 lines of output]
Package libparted was not found in the pkg-config search path.
Perhaps you should add the directory containing `libparted.pc'
to the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable
No package 'libparted' found
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "", line 2, in 
File "", line 34, in 
File "/tmp/pip-install-duf5fzoq/pyparted_8a4ebfd316a743d7b84f7e1e0c77cc80/setup.py", line 60, in 
check_mod_version('libparted', need_libparted_version)
File "/tmp/pip-install-duf5fzoq/pyparted_8a4ebfd316a743d7b84f7e1e0c77cc80/setup.py", line 54, in check_mod_version
modversion = subprocess.check_output(["pkg-config", "--modversion", module]).decode('utf-8').split()[0]
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 424, in check_output
return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
File "/opt/hostedtoolcache/Python/3.9.12/x64/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py", line 528, in run
raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
subprocess.CalledProcessError: Command '['pkg-config', '--modversion', 'libparted']' returned non-zero exit status 1.
[end of output]

note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.
error: metadata-generation-failed

× Encountered error while generating package metadata.
╰─> See above for output.

[image]

Comment: Hi Tianyu Zhou, and welcome to stack overflow!

Comment: Can I make a couple of suggestions?
1: copy and paste the error *text* into the question; that's much better than a screenshot
2: include details of what you have tried so far to solve the problem

Comment: Remember; on this site you're encouraged to [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/72227402/edit) your question as needed, to make it as clear as possible

Answer (score 1):

This is most likely because you have not installed the package.  There are several ways to do this but the easiest is to install via the **Kudu console**.
The [Kudu console](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Kudu-console) gives you direct, elevated command-line access to the App Service server and its file system. This is both a valuable debugging tool and allows for CLI operations such as installing packages.

[image: How to open Kudu Debug Console]

Use `python.exe -m pip install <package_name>` to install a package.

[image: How to manually add python package]

Full Instructions are here:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/python/managing-python-on-azure-app-service?view=vs-2022#azure-app-service-kudu-console